# Invalid mimetype exception in Spring boot rest call

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

I am new to both Spring boot and rest calls.

I am trying to consume a rest service and I do not have any information about that rest API except URL. When I hit that URL from a browser I am getting a response as {key:value}. So, I assumed that it is a JSON response.

I am consuming it in spring boot as follows 
`restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class)` .

This is giving `Invalid mime type "content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1": Invalid token character ':' in token "content-type: text"`

I assume that this error is because response content type is set to text/plain but it is returning JSON format.

EDIT:

Tried this way but did not work.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();     
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",headers);   
ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.GET, 
                                             entity, String.class);
```

How to handle and solve it?

Comment: Instead of `String.class`, create a class that represents the response and use that class.

Comment: Tried that as well but same issue.

Comment: Can you also post the error thrown?

Comment: @Viseshini  Error message:`Invalid mime type "content-type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1": Invalid token character ':' in token "content-type: text" `

Comment: Can you try 
`headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to read about the request headers your REST API needs. `Content-Type` header specifies the media type of the request you're sending to the server. Because you're just getting data from the server you should set the `Accept` header to the kind of response you want i.e., `Accept: application/json`. 
 
Unfortunately, you can't set headers using `getForObject()`. You could try this:

```
URL url = new URL("Enter the URL of the REST endpoint");
        con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                content.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I tried with setting up content-type using header.setAccept() in spring but I do not know why it did not work. It is working as expected with this plain java call.